# Replace commenting system with facebook equiv, link in here for demo purposes?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Please have a look here.

http://www.gamezone.com/news/browser-game-coin-n-carry-lets-you-play-shopkeeper?fb_ref=.Tp7klshGRK4.like&fb_source=profile_oneline

The commenting system used there is linked to facebook, so it shows everything thats commented in a facebook style thread, and that is then linked to facebook.

Id really like to know how this works. I would like to completely replace the default wordpress commenting system, with the facebook version.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would appear that they are just using the comments social plugin provided by facebook. you can change the colour scheme from light to dark. they are using the dark option.

Go to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

add this before the closing body tag:

```
`<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=120489174662204";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
```

then add this where you want the comments to be:

```
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>`
```

make sure you use within the loop and replace example.com with `<?php the_permalink() ?>`

hope this helps

Comment: THanks very much! This is brilliant, means i can put this into an CMS not just wordpress! Thanks!